# English grammar about participle phrase

Tags: grammar, participles, present-participles, participle-clauses

I have got a couple of questions about participles. I would like to understand clearly the usage and grammar of participles.

1. I've been studying participle phrases. And I found a participle phrase can be changed using the adjective clause such as:

> The girl who standing there is my friend (= the girl standing there is my friend )

I wonder if adjective clause can just be changed in continuous tense or not?

2. I know the participle phrase act as an adjective. I wonder does it stress action in progress when it acts as an adjective?

Comment: Note that we can also use [*the book **stood** on the shelf*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+book+stood+on+the+shelf%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) to identify that specific book (as opposed to other books placed elsewhere), in exactly the same way as [*the book **standing** on the shelf*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+book+standing+on+the+shelf%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Whichever verb form is used, there's not really any implication of *action* (whether completed or ongoing) - it just identifies the ***current state/location*** of the book.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  So Using the present participle in the continuous tense is not relative with the present participle as adjective? Is it?

Comment: @BlodMary What grammar book says that *The girl who standing there is my friend (= the girl standing there is my friend )*? -- It is a very odd sentence. (I'd say it's ungrammatical. It should be, at the very least, *The girl who is standing there is my friend*.)

Comment: @Blod: I don't understand your terminology, or what exactly you're asking. But it might help you to know that it's perfectly natural to say *Please pass me that book **sitting** on the shelf behind you*. Where ***sitting*** could be replaced by ***standing*** or ***lying*** (or even omitted completely) without significantly affecting the meaning. And regardless of how it's expressed, the speaker wouldn't be thinking in terms of the book actually "doing" anything at all - he's just identifying *that specific book* by specifying its location.

Comment: @Damkerng: I'm sure OP's specific example is a simple typo, but you have to be careful about identifying all such constructions as "ungrammatical". It would be hard to argue with *When he awoke to the sound of her raucous snoring, the girl who singing in the club last night had seemed so alluring now just disgusted him*. (On syntactic grounds, at least - I don't defend either the characters or their behaviour! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your example is invalid as a counter-example. It parses as "[...] { the girl ( who ( singing in the club last night ) had seemed so alluring ) now just disgusted him }" where indeed you have the relative clause headed by "who" with a full verb "had seemed", and "singing ..." is merely a participial phrase that adverbially modifies "had seemed" by describing the referent of "who".

Comment: @user21820: Fair enough. Would you like this example any better to illustrate my point? [*Happy is the man **who knowing truth** walks in its ways, and unhappy is he who goes in the way that is not Truth's way.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22happy+is+the+man+who+knowing%22) I think you'd struggle to find any relevant *syntactic* difference between the verbs in ***knowing** truth / **standing** there* and ***walks** in its ways / **is** my friend*. But by all means give it a shot.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your new example is of the same type. "{ happy } is { the man ( who ( knowing truth ) walks in its ways ) } and ...". "knowing truth" again is merely a participial phrase adverbially modifying "walks" by describing the referent of the relative pronoun "who". I think you keep mistaking the participial clauses for something else.

Comment: @user21820: I have no real interest in the "grammatical naming of the parts" exercise. I was just pointing to Damkerng that although our first reaction to OP's example is "that's ungrammatical", it's not really possible on purely ***syntactic*** grounds to debar *The girl **who standing there** is my friend would be my enemy if she moved over to stand on the Dark Side*. If you *still* won't accept that, I guess there's nothing more I can say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Oh if you are saying that the phrase can be part of a larger grammatically correct sentence, then why should I disagree? It did not occur to me that it could be what the asker's example was. Either way, the example is not a clear one since the two phrases cannot function in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If your example is meant to be a sentence, then it is ungrammatical and should have been:

> The girl who **is** standing there is my friend.

It breaks down as follows:

> The girl is my friend. Which girl? The girl who is standing there.

"who is standing there" is called a relative clause, signalled by the relative pronoun "who", which is the subject of the relative clause. The main verb of the relative clause is the present continuous verb "is standing". Where the standing takes place is indicated by the adverb "there".

You are right that in this particular case it is more or less equivalent to:

> The girl standing there is my friend.

It can also work with more complicated cases, though the shorter version might sound odd to some people:

> The boy [who is] writing on the board is my neighbour.

Note that the shorter form does not by itself necessitate present tense. For example:

> The man [who was] sitting on our right stood up and left.

Also, shortening is also allowed when the main verb of the relative clause is the copulative ("is / was / will be") and the predicate complement (sometimes called "object") is a preposition or a past participle functioning as an adjective, such as:

> The woman [who is] in this picture is my grandmother.
>
> The book [that had been] on the table had disappeared!
>
> The houses [that were] buffeted by the incredible wind have all fallen down.
>
> Those [who will be] leaving next week will be given a farewell dinner tomorrow.

There are various additional cases where shortening is permitted, and this is not in any way an exhaustive list:

> The people [whom] I met at the park today were very friendly.
>
> This child [that is] here needs rest.